# Density estimate with large array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm using the [`gaussian_kde`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) function in SciPy to generate a kernel density estimate:

```
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde
from scipy.stats import norm
from numpy import linspace,hstack
from pylab import plot,show,hist

# creating data with two peaks
sampD1 = norm.rvs(loc=-1.0,scale=1,size=300)
sampD2 = norm.rvs(loc=2.0,scale=0.5,size=300)
samp = hstack([sampD1,sampD2])

# obtaining the pdf (my_pdf is a function!)
my_pdf = gaussian_kde(samp)

# plotting the result
x = linspace(-5,5,100)
plot(x,my_pdf(x),'r') # distribution function
hist(samp,normed=1,alpha=.3) # histogram
show()
```

The above code works, but can be prohibitively slow with a very large number of samples.

Instead of storing my samples in arrays, I have a dictionary with key/value pairs of `value: counts`. For example the array `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]` would be encoded in this histogram dictionary as:

`{1:3, 2:2, 3:1}`.

My questions is, how can I generate a kernel density estimate using a dictionary data structure? As an example input, consider this dictionary, where the value of 6 was seen 2081 times:

```
samp = {1: 1000, 2: 2800, 3: 6900, 4: 4322:, 5: 2300, 6: 2081}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hmm, scipy's gaussian_kde takes only array-like structures as input. I'm fairly sure you can't feed it a dict. Moreover your new data structure only compress the input data, but does not change the processing's speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do Gaussian KDE yourself: you just first need to create the simple histogram with small enough step size. Then convolve the result with the Gaussian using fftconvolve
(scipy.signal.fftconvolve)

```
import numpy as np, numpy.random,scipy,scipy.stats,scipy.signal,matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 1e5
minx = -10
maxx = 10
bins = 10000
w = 0.1 # kernel sigma

xs1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=N)
xs2 = np.random.normal(1.9, 0.01, size=N)
xs = np.r_[xs1, xs2]
hh,loc = scipy.histogram(xs, range=(minx, maxx), bins=bins)
kernel = scipy.stats.norm.pdf((loc[1:]+loc[:-1]) * .5, 0, w)
kde = scipy.signal.fftconvolve(hh, kernel, 'same')
plt.plot((loc[1:] + loc[:-1])*.5, kde)
```

Answer (score 1):

To the first question:

If your data is univariate, then you can use an fft version of kernel density estimation which is much faster.
For example in statsmodels http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.KDEUnivariate.html

To the second question:

If you already have a histogram as your data, then you can use histogram smoothing. But I don't know of any function in python that would do this out of the box.
The fft version in statsmodels is binning the data first. The second step is similar to a convolution of the histogram. It might be possible to use something similar for histogram data.